# Card with FlatList React native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

im trying to achieve message view by using card with flatlist how can i arrange few elements of my flat list the left screen right screen.

I want the green card to be on the left side of the screen

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Do you have an example of what your `renderItem` looks like and what the `data` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-gifted-chat` for your desired result.

```
npm install react-native-gifted-chat --save

import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat'

export function Example() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setMessages([
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: 'Hello developer',
        createdAt: new Date(),
        user: {
          _id: 2,
          name: 'React Native',
          avatar: 'https://placeimg.com/140/140/any',
        },
      },
    ])
  }, [])

  const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
    setMessages(previousMessages => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
  }, [])

  return (
    <GiftedChat
      messages={messages}
      onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
      user={{
        _id: 1,
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: im trying to build a custom chat application without react-native-gifted-chat. With gifted chat package its pretty straight forward.

Comment: then you have to share your flatlist code.